# Synchronize a bindable property with a command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

Is there a way to execute a command when property changes with specified binding delay?

As an example let's use CheckBox that has property IsChecked with Delay=1000 (1 sec) and Command that invokes when IsChecked property changes:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<CheckBox Command="{Binding Command}"
          Content="Hello"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Delay=1000}" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        if (_isChecked != value)
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            MessageBox.Show("Property Changed"); 
        }
    }
}

public ICommand Command { get; } = new RelayCommand(obj => MessageBox.Show("Command Invoked"));
```

When clicking on checkbox the MessageBox.Show("Command Invoked") invokes first and then MessageBox.Show("Property Changed");

Final output:

`"Command Invoked" -\> after 1 sec delay -\> "Property Changed"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the operation from the property `set()`, depending on the delay of the `Binding`.

Or you delay the operation explicitly using a timer or `Task.Delay`:

```cs
public ICommand SomeCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSomeCommandDelayedAsync);

private async Task ExecuteSomeCommandDelayedAsync(object commandParameter)
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  MessageBox.Show("Command Invoked");
}
```

To replicate the delay behavior of the binding engine, you would have to use a timer and reset it on every invocation and honor the latest change/command parameter exclusively.

The following example uses the `System.Threading.Timer` (if you need to access UI elements, or `DispatcherObject` instances in general, you should use the `DispatcherTimer` instead):

```cs
public ICommand SomeCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSomeCommand);

// Important: this Timer implements IDisposable/IDisposableAsync.
// It must be disposed if it is no longer needed!
private System.Threading.Timer CommandDelayTimer { get; } 
private object SomeCommandCommandParameter { get; set; }

public Constructor()
  => this.CommandDelayTimer = new Timer(OnCommandDelayElapsed);

private async Task ExecuteSomeCommand(object commandParameter)
{
  // Capture latest parameter value and drop the previous
  this.SomeCommandCommandParameter = commandParameter;

  // Start/reset the timer.
  // This timer is configured to execute only once (period time = 0).
  _ = this.CommandDelayTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}

private void OnCommandDelayElapsed(object? state)
{
  SomeCommandOperation(state);
}

// The operation that the command is supposed to invoke after a delay
private void SomeCommandOperation(object commandParameter)
{  
  MessageBox.Show("Command Invoked");
}
```

Comment: `You can execute the operation from the property set(), depending on the delay of the Binding` - You mean instead of a command I should just bind to a property and execute operations that I need?
What about Command with `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` - If I change the property (in less than a second) and change property one more time, then "Command Invoked" will call 2 times, and "Property Changed" only one

Comment: 1) Yes, the CheckBox already modifies the property value on click. You can use that as a trigger for the operation instead of having the CheckBox invoke the command for you. 2) Yes, the binding engine will not queue property changes. It discards the previous change and updates the property with the last change (after the delay). The delay timer is always reset if the property change occurred before the delay time has elapsed. You can't replicate this behavior with `Task.Delay`. You would have to use a timer instead (e.g. DispatcherTimer). Let me update the answer to give an example.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Good example. I think it is possible to make a custom command with this behavior using your example. I prefer the set() answer cuz it's more readable and easier. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Thanks for your appreciation. Yes, that's a very good idea to move the behavior to a e.g. `RoutedDelayCommand`.